# How to store a string with delimiters in an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$string = '"Joe Bob" "John Doe" "Amber Page" "Jordan Tole"';
```

I want to store it in an array with each item in between the " " being an element inside of the array.

e.g.

```
$Array = StringToArray($string);
```

Comment: your current string definition is a syntax error

Comment: No matter what these answers suggest, __don't__ use explode(): use str_getcsv() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of [PHP's explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)  you could use  to build an array of the names like this:

```
$string = '"Joe Bob" "John Doe" "Amber Page" "Jordan Tole"';
$string = substr($string,1,-1);
$names = explode('" "', $string);
```

This would output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joe Bob
    [1] => John Doe
    [2] => Amber Page
    [3] => Jordan Tole
)
```

Comment: I messed up that String, I forgot to mention that the individual items in the string can have spaces in them, I made the edit above.

Comment: I think maybe the space inbetween the quotes is throwing things off, It works kind of if I do explode('"', $string); but if I put the space in between quotes like this: explode('" "', $string) it outputs it all in one element in the array.  Is there some special way to specify a space in the explode function?  When I do it like this: explode('"', $string); it seperates them but creates a lot of blank elements.

Comment: Hmmm, the code I have above works fine. Is what you're testing with different?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) to pull the string apart:

```
$string = '"Joe" "John" "Amber" "Jordan"';

$names = preg_split('~(^"|" "|"$)~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(3) "Joe"
  [1]=> string(4) "John"
  [2]=> string(5) "Amber"
  [3]=> string(6) "Jordan"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pending you correct the string above..

```
$string = '"Joe" "John" "Amber" "Jordan"';
```

using explode. `<?php $arr = explode('" "', $string);` will provide you the following: `$arr = array( 0 => '"Joe"', 1 => '"John"'...`

---

However if you meant:

```
<?php
$string = "Joe John Amber Jordan";
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
// will provide the samething without the " and ".
```

Comment: To get even rid of the quotation marks: `$arr = explode('" "', trim($string, '"'));`

Comment: i updated my answer to include an example for your updated code in your question

Comment: For some reason that updated explode isn't working and I can't figure out why.  It just stores the entire string in on element in the array instead of separating them.